# Ação no botão voltar quando o teclado está ativo

Tags: android, teclado

Estou tentando usar a ação do botão voltar para aparecer um menu na minha aplicação, com o método onKeyUp. Assim que a tecla de voltar fosse clicado, o menu deveria imediatamente aparecer.

Na minha aplicação trabalho com tabHost, são 3 telas, nas duas primeiras há menu normal, na terceira é uma tela de pesquisa, e quando vou pra ela, o teclado automaticamente sobe, e o menu some, pois neste momento ele é desnecessário.

Minha dificuldade tá sendo em mostrar novamente esse menu após ser clicado o botão voltar, ele funciona de certa forma, mas só aparece no segundo clique do botão voltar. Ou seja, o primeiro clique serve só para baixar o teclado, e o segundo que aparece o menu. Mas quero que no primeiro clique já baixe o teclado e apareça o menu, e nao estou conseguindo. Segue os métodos, isso tudo na MainActivity.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    if (event != null && KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK == event.getKeyCode() || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        Log.i("BOTAO VOLTAR", "BOTÃO VOLTAR CLICADO!!!");
        hideShowTabs(false);
    }
    return false;
}

public void hideShowTabs(boolean option) {

        if (option)
            tabHost.getTabWidget().setVisibility(View.GONE);
        else
            tabHost.getTabWidget().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Alguém pode me dizer pq ele nao funciona no primeiro clique ?? Como faria pra funcionar ?? 
Tenho duas opções para fazer: identificar quando o teclado for baixado, ou quando a tecla voltar for clicada, para aparecer o menu. Aceito sugestões, desde jpa agradeço.

Answer (score 0):

Isso é possível, mas infelizmente o SDK Android não oferece uma maneira simples de resolver esta questão. **Antes de tentar implementar a solução eu recomendaria refletir bastante se você realmente precisará interceptar o `onBackPressed()`** quando o teclado estiver presente.

Minha resposta é baseada [nesta esclarecedora contribuição](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5811630/4871489)

1. criar uma versão customizada do View onde você precisa recuperar o onKeyPressed
2. Subscreva `dispatchKeyEventPreIme(KeyEvent event)`
3. Processe o evento a sua maneira. Na snipped abaixo eu optei por processar o evento no objeto inscrito e retornar um resultado para a View customizada dar prosseguimento ou não com suas ações padrão.
4. Crie uma interface para receber o evento `onBackPressed` na View
5. Inscreva sua Atividade (ou outro objeto) para receber o evento

**OBS 1** - Você precisará compreender o mínimo sobre a criação de View customizadas.

**OBS 2** - Achei a questão interessante e pretendo fazer um tutorial sobre o assunto com mais detalhes. Devo fazer isso ainda nessa semana. Depois posto o link aqui.

**OBS 3** - Você pode conferir no [meu gitHub](https://github.com/tinmegali/Android-CustomView-OnBackPressed/tree/master) a implementação completa

;

```
 */ Registre o callback para receber o evento
 */
public void setListener(BackPressed callback){
    mCallback = callback;
}

/**
 * Subscreva o evento <code>dispatchKeyEventPreIme</code>.
 * Intercepte o tipo de evento <code>KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK</code>
 * e faça o que quiser com ele.
 */
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEventPreIme(KeyEvent event) {
    Log.d(TAG, "dispatchKeyEventPreIme(" + event + ")");
    if ( mCallback != null ) {
        // O View verifica o tipo de evento
        // dá a oportunidade do objeto inscrito
        // processar o evento e anula a ação padrão
        // em caso de retorno positivo
        if ( event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            KeyEvent.DispatcherState state = getKeyDispatcherState();
            if (state != null) {
                if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN
                        && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
                    state.startTracking(event, this);
                    Log.i(TAG, "KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN");
                    return true;
                } else if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP
                        && !event.isCanceled() && state.isTracking(event)) {
                    if ( mCallback.editTextOnBackPressed() ) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "KeyEvent.ACTION_UP | cancelando processo padrão");
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        Log.i(TAG, "KeyEvent.ACTION_UP | processando o processo padrão");
                        return super.dispatchKeyEventPreIme(event);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Log.i(TAG, "Returning generic onBackPressed");
    return super.dispatchKeyEventPreIme(event);
}


public interface BackPressed {
    /**
     * Listener para eventos onBackPressed com o teclado presente.
     * O objeto inscrito tem a oportunidade de processar o evento
     * e definir se o <code>View</code> deve seguir ou não com sua
     * ação padrao.
     * @return  true: <code>View</code> abandona a ação padrão e executa
     *                  somente o bloco definido antes do retorno
     *          false: <code>View</code> executa o código definido antes do
     *                  retorno e dá sequência a ação convencional
     */
    boolean editTextOnBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: Pois é amigo, mas eu não entendo muito bem sobre view customizadas. Vc poderia explicar mais detalhadamente ?

Comment: camarada, São muitos passos para te explicar sobre Custom View e a resposta ficaria inclusive fora do tópico da sua pergunta. A resposta para sua pergunta original já foi dada. Sua dificuldade em implementar um Custom View já é outra questão. Devo postar no meu blog www.tinmegali.com uma dica sobre isso em breve. Você pode aguardar ou abrir uma pergunta sobre Custom View no stackOverflow. Boa sorte.

Comment: Eu consegui, da forma que disse funcionou. Obgggg